# Cartoonize and colorize

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to make a specific image filter, processing a picture to cartoonize and change the colors.

Here you can see the original and the expected result: http://codingfocus.com/ieffect.jpg

I'm not sure which will be a good approach, I started with a grayscale, posterize and color replacement ranges based on how dark is every pixel, but the result is pretty pixelated and not near to what I would like to obtain. http://codingfocus.com/test3.jpg

Comment: Do you know how the original was generated?  ostagram.ru uses a convolutional neural network

Comment: It was generated with photoshop, but the result doesn't have to be exact, just a good enough approximation. Didn't know about convolutional neural networks, looks very cool, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: So the original was created by hand? Or by a Photoshop filter?